# Appium IOS never initialises driver variable

Tags: appium-ios

I am running appium on a mac and running the code on an different machine. all good in that is open the simulator etc. However my test still fails as it never goes into the test. The driver variable below evaluates to null and it does not pick it up. Can you help

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.iOS;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Enums;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;



namespace AutoItX_Testing
{

    [TestFixture]
    class IOSDemo
    {

        public IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver;

          //  public IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Start()
        {
            //Setting Capabilities
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "10.1");
            //capabilities.SetCapability("platform", "Mac");
           // capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "iPhone 6");
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName, "XCUITest");
            capabilities.SetCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BundleId, "com.softworks.selfservice.app");
            //capabilities.SetCapability("native-instruments-lib", true);
            //capabilities.SetCapability("deviceReadyTimeout",100000);
           // capabilities.SetCapability("deviceReadyTimeout", "100000");
           // capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "18000000000000");
           // capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 18000000000000);
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "IOS");
            capabilities.SetCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LocationServicesEnabled, "false");
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NewCommandTimeout, "900000");
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NewCommandTimeout, 900000);
             capabilities.SetCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LaunchTimeout, "50000");
             capabilities.SetCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LaunchTimeout, 50000);
             capabilities.SetCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.NativeInstrumentsLib, true);

           // capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "/Users/itsoftworks/Desktop/UICatalog7/UICatalog.app");
            capabilities.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "/Users/itsoftworks/Desktop/SelfService/Self Service.app");
           driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(
                               new Uri("http://192.168.17.85:4723/wd/hub"),
                                capabilities);
            while (driver ==null)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("driver is still null");
            }
           // driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.17.85:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
           // Thread.Sleep(1000000000);
           // driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000000));

        }

        [Test]

          public void VerifyMenuSimulator()
        {
            //Test to login into app

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("it worked"); ;

            //driver.manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(Timespan.FromSeconds(60));
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//UIATextField[1]")).SendKeys("username");
          //  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("///UIASecureTextField[1]")).SendKeys("password");
           // driver.FindElement(By.XPath("///UIAButton[1]")).Click();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the appium full log ?

Comment: Hi. I will close this one, now